# Authenticate linux based user in java

Tags: java, linux, authentication

I have a username and password for a particular user in Linux i need to verify that if the user is valid or not using java?

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java way to do this would be [JAAS](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html), but you'll still need a LoginModule that works with Linux. [Here's](http://jaas-pam.sourceforge.net/index.html) a beta implementation that claims to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java Runtime-object to run the command line commands that suit your needs.
[Runtime API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Comment: There are probably several ways to do it. One might be using 'su' -command and seeing if the login is succesful or not. It might also be possible to parse the password file, but that sounds quite unsecure.

Comment: Actually with su command i can verify the username but not the password of a given user can u suggest a command to verify both parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer the question but may be helpful for others. 
JSch library http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ can help to achieve this. Below method will return string if authentication is successful otherwise it will throw an exception.

```
public String authenticate(String host, String user, String password) throws JSchException {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        Properties obj_Properties = new Properties();
        obj_Properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(obj_Properties);
        session.connect(5000);
        String version = session.getServerVersion();
        session.disconnect();
        return version;
    }
```